# Cytoscape graph builder (drag-and-drop new nodes)

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am looking to use Cytoscape.js to build an interactive web based graph builder. Is it possible to handle a drop event to create a new node or link? If not, what options, if any exist for interactive graph building using the API? It looks like I may be able to use the click event or the radial menu plugin to do something like this but I'm interested in other options. Are there any good examples out there of doing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cytoscape.js has an [extension API](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions) that can be used to create reusable components like you suggest.  There are several existing extensions which you can use in addition to the documentation as examples.

It seems someone has made [a similar extension](https://github.com/ayushkr19/cytoscape.js-nodeadd), but it’s straightfoward to create your own using any of the [documented API functions](http://js.cytoscape.org).

We’re working to streamline the extension writing and submission process so it’s easier to share your extensions with others in v2.3.

Comment: This is very helpful @maxkfranz!  Thanks for taking the time to answer.  Is there a list of all available plugins somewhere? I've seen the plugins listed on the main Cytoscape page and also on the jQuery plugin registry [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/cytoscape.js/).  Is there somewhere else that I should be looking for a complete catalog?

Comment: Those lists can only be updated if someone submits their extension.  Otherwise, you'll have to find them with Google etc.

Comment: Just have to modify nodeadd code to pass in cy instance to the extension instead of trying to retrieve cy instance via jquery, otherwise great starting point